# Syntax for ArcGIS ICalculator object?

Tags: arcobjects, field-calculator, vba

I have a code snippet that I can't figure out:

```
'Define a calculator for NewArea field
    pCalculator = New Calculator
    With pCalculator
        .Cursor = pCursor
        .PreExpression = "Dim dbarea as double" & vbCrLf _
                       & "Dim pArea as IArea" & vbCrLf _
                       & "Set pArea = [Shape]" & vbCrLf _
                       & "dbArea = pArea.area"
        .Expression = "dbArea"
        .Field = "NewArea"
    End With

    'Calculate the field values of NewArea field
    pCalculator.Calculate()
```

What is pCalculator calculating here?  What is [Shape] in this context?  I'm migrating this old VBA code to Python, and I'm stuck at this segment.

A more general question, what is the significance of the square brackets in the pre-expression?  Are they placeholders for the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this is doing is calculating the area of each feature. You can easily do the same thing with the Python version of the parser with `!shape.area!`. See the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_the_Calculate_Field_tool/005s00000029000000/).

Using ArcObjects, I would suggest using an [update cursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001mm000000) as in this sample (relevant code posted below): [Calculate area geoprocessing function tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002r6000000.htm)

```vb
' Create an Update Cursor
indexA = inputFeatureClass.FindField(sField)
Dim updateCursor As IFeatureCursor = inputFeatureClass.Update(Nothing, False)
Dim updateFeature As IFeature = updateCursor.NextFeature()
Dim geometry As IGeometry
Dim area As IArea
Dim dArea As Double

Do While Not updateFeature Is Nothing
    geometry = updateFeature.Shape
    area = CType(geometry, IArea)
    dArea = area.Area
    updateFeature.Value(indexA) = dArea
    updateCursor.UpdateFeature(updateFeature)
    updateFeature.Store()
    updateFeature = updateCursor.NextFeature()
Loop

' Release the update cursor to remove the lock on the input data.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(updateCursor)
```

Comment: Months later I'm back at this exact snippet.  This code throws a "General error executing calculator." Do you know why?  I'm writing a VB add-in, and this code came from VBA. Is there some syntax issue that VB doesn't like here?