# ARCGIS 10, VB.NET, calculate centroids

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects

I have migrated an toolbar initially developed for ArcGIS 9.3.  This tool is used by non-programmer or cartographers.

One procedure is called to generate centroids of attributes table and after to launch an calculation.

Anyway,

The source code used in 9.3 was :

(A)

```
    'instantiating new calculator and cursor
    pCalculator = New Calculator
    pCursor = CType(pFeatureClass.Update(Nothing, True), ICursor)

    'Centroid Y
    With pCalculator
        .Cursor = pCursor
        .PreExpression = "Dim pGeomShp as IGeometry" & vbNewLine & "Set pGeomShp = [shape]" & vbNewLine & "Dim pArea as IArea" & vbNewLine & "Set pArea = pGeomShp" & vbNewLine
        .Expression = "pArea.Centroid.Y"
        .Field = "centroidY"
    End With


    'try & catch *************************************************
    Try
        pCalculator.Calculate()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This was working until moving to ArcIS 10 (an upper). A crash was observed while launching `pCalculator.Calculate()`.

I’ve migrated this code that way (like proposed here [Syntax for ArcGIS ICalculator object?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52983/syntax-for-arcgis-icalculator-object/198681#198681) )  :

(B)

```
    Dim nCentroidXFieldIndex As Integer = pFeatureClass.FindField("centroidX")
    Dim nCentroidYFieldIndex As Integer = pFeatureClass.FindField("centroidY")
    Dim nBldg_sizeFieldIndex As Integer = pFeatureClass.FindField("Bldg_size")


    If TypeOf pFeatureClass Is IFeatureClass Then            
        If TypeOf pFeatureCursor Is IFeatureCursor Then

            Dim pArea As IArea
            Dim pFeature As IFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature()
            Dim myProgressCalc As New FileProgressForm
            myProgressCalc.set_maximum(iTotalRecords)
            myProgressCalc.Show()
            myProgressCalc.Text = "Veuillez patienter svp"
            myProgressCalc.lblProgress.Text = "Calcul des données géographiques"
            myProgressCalc.Update()

            pArea = CType(pFeature.Shape, IArea)

            While pFeature IsNot Nothing
                pFeature.Value(nCentroidXFieldIndex) = pArea.Centroid.X
                pFeature.Value(nCentroidYFieldIndex) = pArea.Centroid.Y
                pFeature.Value(nBldg_sizeFieldIndex) = pArea.Area

                pFeature.Store()
                pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature

                myProgressCalc.Go()

            End While
            myProgressCalc.Close()
        End If
    End If
```

It’s working but it’s working extremely slowly !   The first code (A) was executed in less than 3 minutes. The new one (B) in 25 minutes !

In fact, I just want to programmaticaly call a the new calculate geometry tool (when displaying attributes table - calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm )

Screen capture 1
[image]

or Arc tool => Data Management Tools => Entities => Add geometric attributes (/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm )

Screen capture 2
[image]

or any other methods !

Both tools are working great in ArcGis Desktop but I can’t find my way to make them work in VB.NET.

I'm using ArcGis 10.2 after having used ArcGis 10.0. The error was the same...

Sorry for screen capture in french and for poor english speaking.